# Concurrent Calls to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been sitting 2 days with this problem, but I cant seem to get to the end of it.
I hope someone here has some experience in this or atleast went through this at some point.

We couldnt connect to our WCF service when making 2 concurrent calls to it.Couldnt get any errors nowhere either.So I used 'Microsoft service trace viewer' and the error I got was:

**There is not a header with name SomeTest and namespace http://www.website.com/ in the message.**

We can reproduce the problem by a testtool that open's 2 threads at exact the same time, thus it only happens when running concurrently.

Now I looked at the StackTrace and saw its failing because SomeTest gets lost in the headermessage in the second call.Why is this?

I've read somewhere that the second call will loose its messageheaders when it happens at the exact time as the first call? Is this true? Can someone give me some tips or advise regarding this.I cant really get much info online

Comment: Hard to believe the headers would vanish just like that. I think you should start by using some sniffer (Fiddler maybe) to understand if the headers are lost on client or server side.

Comment: `I've read somewhere that the second call will loose its messageheaders when it happens at the exact time as the first call` Are you using the same channel instance for the two threads? I don't know if the class is thread-safe, I'd recommend using a distinct channel per thread.

Comment: Youd do have a point there, but User1 sits in Japan and User2 sits in America.They both hit the service at exact same time.This same issue still arrises.Why, it will then be 2 distinct channels.

Comment: `I've read somewhere that the second call will loose its messageheaders` Where did you read this?

Comment: @user1702369 You haven't indicated in the question that you've been able to reproduce the issue with two distinct clients (rather than two threads in the same client). That's an important piece of information.

Comment: I wasnt able to reproduce 2 Clients scenario, therefore I created a tool to simulate this.Our problem is that all seems to go well and then suddenly an error.Its intermittadley.We traced it as far as we could see.It happens when 2 Clients(Anywhere) hits the service at excactly the same time.Therefore we wrote a tool that hits the service at the same time to try to reproduce the problem and behold we get an error: There is not a header with name SomeTest and namespace http://www.website.com/ in the message.